# S3Proxy - Sort List Bucket Results Based on LastModified

Tags: s3proxy

I am trying to see if it's possible to have the list of files returned from a normal list bucket operation returned based on the file's LastModified attribute. If it is possible, what is the syntax to do so using a url?

I haven't found any documentation regarding this functionality.

Thank you for the help!